# Как вытащить данные по дате (проигнорировав время)?

Tags: sql, sqlite3

Есть БД в sqlite3, там есть колонка с datetime (например 2020-08-20 20:00:05). Мне нужно вытащить все данные за 2020-08-20 проигнорировал время. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По моему ты должен использовать функцию date а не datetime, он вернёт только дату.